# Next and Zustang auth with cookie and persist storage

Tags: authentication, next.js, cookies, authorization, zustand

I am using Next 14 and used route handlers to implement authentification in following way:

1. in route.ts I log user in, create jwt, store it in cookie with userId as payload
2. on client, I have request to this route's path
3. after receiving response data user, I save it in zustang store which persists (meaning that it saves this user in local storage).
   I need client side user for conditionally rendering certain components and pieces

NOW THE ISSUE: I have 2 pieces of user: one in cookie, another in zustang. I figured, what happens if, for whatever reason, cookie is deleted, or zustang user from local storage? What if iI loose one? So I figured I need to sync these two.
Since I have app wrapper component which renders app only after monut (to avoid hydration issues due to having zustand), in this same wrapper, I have logic where I check if both cookie (which I get from request sent from client to route) and zustang user are present: If either one of two are missing or if user id from cookie !== user id from zustange, I trgger logout.
NOW, is this valid what am I doing? Do I really need both cookie and zustang user (Which I think I do). Is this 'problem' reasonable? How would you approach it?